# Zend Framework Basic Request Workflow

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework

I was going through this PDF (http://nethands.de/download/zenddispatch_en.pdf) that elaborates the detailed workflow of a Zend Framework request.

It seems very confusing to me and so was wondering if someone can be kind enough to list these step by step in simple terms to me?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: if you looking for the 10,000 ft overview of how to use zend framework start Here [Rob Allen's Tutorial for ZF 1.11](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-tutorial/). It'll take about 1.5 hours to type it in and make it work.

Answer (score 1):

The steps are simply:

1. Routing
2. Dispatch

The PDF looks complicated because it is listing all the places you can hook into this process, along with all the objects that are affected by it. For example with a controller plugin you can write some code that will run just before the routing (`routeStartup`), and just after routing (`routeShutdown`). In the PDF you'll see these represented as the green box above and below the red 'Routing' box.

The diagram in the manual is perhaps a little clearer: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.basics.html

Comment: Hi Tim, in that zend manual link you shared, why does not the diagram have the zend framework's "front controller" and "bootstrap" process mentioned anywhere?

Comment: That particular diagram is in the controller part of the manual, so it covers the controller part of the process. Bootstrapping and the front controller part of of the process happen before that.